# Passing table with fields as an argument to Lua function from C++?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I would like to know how to form a Lua table with fields and values so I can pass it as an argument to a Lua function from C++.

I know how to form a table using indices but I don't know how to from a table made of fields and values.

For example, I want to send this table to a Lua function as an argument from C++.

```
t = {xpos = 50, ypos = 80, message = 'hello'}
```

The below code is the closest I could get, but it's just indexed table with no field name.

```
lua_getglobal(L, "myLuaFunc");
if (lua_type(L, -1) == LUA_TFUNCTION)
{
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 1);
    lua_pushnumber(L, 50);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 2);
    lua_pushnumber(L, 80);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 3);
    lua_pushstring(L, 'hello');   
    lua_settable(L, -3);
    if (lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0))
        std::cout << "Error : " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << std::endl;   
}
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Comment: So we can suppose (from the example), you already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670094/passing-a-lua-table-from-c-to-lua-script)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just did. but I don't think it's helpful.

Comment: I am not a 100% sure how _field names_ for a table are passed to lua, but I'd guess you can use some other interface function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `lua_setfield`, which makes the code shorter and probably easier to read:

```
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 50);         // xpos = 50
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "xpos");
    lua_pushinteger(L, 80);         // ypos = 80
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "ypos");
    lua_pushstring(L, "hello");     // message = "hello"
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "message");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly.  If you want strings as keys in the table, then just push strings instead of numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <lua.hpp>

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    char const script[] = "function test(t)\n"
                          "    print(t.xpos)\n"
                          "    print(t.ypos)\n"
                          "    print(t.message)\n"
                          "end";

    if (luaL_dostring(L, script) != 0) {
        std::cerr << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
        lua_close(L);
        return 1;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "test");
    if (lua_isfunction(L, -1)) {
        lua_newtable(L);
        // xpos = 50
        lua_pushstring(L, "xpos");
        lua_pushinteger(L, 50);
        lua_settable(L, -3);
        // ypos = 80
        lua_pushstring(L, "ypos");
        lua_pushinteger(L, 80);
        lua_settable(L, -3);
        // message = "hello"
        lua_pushstring(L, "message");
        lua_pushstring(L, "hello");
        lua_settable(L, -3);

        if (lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0) != 0) {
            std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
            lua_close(L);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    lua_close(L);
}
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I wanted to find out. Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: @ZackLee You could also have read the documentation for [`lua_settable`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_settable).

Comment: @ZackLee, see my answer

Comment: Could you guys please check my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230305/passing-table-with-subtable-to-lua-function-from-c